# Test passing for button disabled when it should not (Formik | react-testing library)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, formik, react-testing

I am using a formik form to sign up and testing it with react testing library. The submit button is disabled if the email or password fields are invalid. I am testing if my btn is enabled or disabled when i type certain input. I am performing 2 tests the first one with invalid inputs and the second with valid inputs but the first one is always passing even if it shouldn't. The 2nd test is behaving as it should

```
const MockedSignUpFormView=()=>{
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <SignUpFormView/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}


it('btn is disabled if sign up with wrong credentials ',async () => {
        render(<MockedSignUpFormView />);
        const emailInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', {  name: /email address/i});
        const passInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
        const confirmPassInput = screen.getByLabelText(/confirm password/i);
        const signUpBtn = screen.getByRole('button', {  name: /sign up/i})
      
        userEvent.type(emailInput,'mnbmbm@gmail.com')
    
        userEvent.type(passInput,'sadasdas')
     
        userEvent.type(confirmPassInput,'czxcxzcxz')
        
        await waitFor(async ()=>{ 
            expect(signUpBtn).not.toHaveAttribute('disabled')})
        
        screen.debug()
    });

    it('btn is enabled if sign up with right credentials ',async () => {
        render(<MockedSignUpFormView />);
        const emailInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', {  name: /email address/i});
        const passInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
        const confirmPassInput = screen.getByLabelText(/confirm password/i);
        const signUpBtn = screen.getByRole('button', {  name: /sign up/i})
      
        userEvent.type(emailInput,'mnbmbm@gmail.com')
    
        userEvent.type(passInput,'czxcxzcxz')
     
        userEvent.type(confirmPassInput,'czxcxzcxz')
        
        await waitFor(async ()=>{ 
            expect(signUpBtn).toBeEnabled()})
        
        screen.debug()
    });
```

I am using screen.debug and i am getting disabled on the first btn but still test keeps passing for this `expect(signUpBtn).not.toHaveAttribute('disabled')})` and this   `expect(signUpBtn).not.toBeDisabled()`

Sreen.debug() for first btn `<button class="login__btn" disabled="" type="submit">`
Sreen.debug() for 2nd btn `<button class="login__btn" type="submit">`

SignUpFormView component

```
const SignUpFormView=(props:any)=>{
    const [error,setError]=useState(false);
    const navigate=useNavigate ();
 
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Formik
            initialValues={{
                email: "",
                password:"",
                confirmPassword:""
            }}
            validationSchema={Yup.object({   
            password: Yup.string()
                .min(6, "Must be 6 characters or more")
                .required("Required"),
            confirmPassword: Yup.string()
                .min(6, "Must be 6 characters or more")
                .required("Required")
                .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match'),
            email: Yup.string()
                .email("Invalid email address`")
                .required("Required"),
            })}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    props.onSubmitHandler(values.email,values.password).then((userCredential:any) => {
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    
                        navigate('/home');
                      
                    }).catch((err:any)=>{
                        setError(err.message);
                    })
                }}>
                {formik => {
                    return (
                        <nav className={classes["nav"]}>
                            <h2 className={classes['nav__detail']}>Sign Up</h2>
                            <Form className={classes['form__login']}>
                                <Input 
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    type="email"
                                
                                />
                                <Input
                                    label="Password"
                                    name="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder='Password' 
                                  
                                />
                                <Input
                                    label="Confirm Password"
                                    name="confirmPassword"
                                    type="password"  
                                    
                                />
                                {(formik.isSubmitting || error) /*&& renderResponseItem(formik.isSubmitting,error)*/}
                                {!formik.isSubmitting && <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid || formik.isSubmitting ? true :false} className={classes['login__btn']}>Sign Up</button>}
                            </Form>
                            <Link to='/'>Have an account? Login</Link>
                        </nav>
                    )
                }
            }
        </Formik>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Input component

```
import  React  from 'react';
import { useField } from "formik";
import classes from './InputView.module.css';

interface Props{
  name:string,
  id?:string,
  placeholder?:string,
  label:string,
  type:string
}

const Input:React.FC<Props>=(props)=>{
    const [field, meta] = useField(props);

    const inputClasses=meta.touched && meta.error ? `${classes.input} ${classes.error}`:`${classes.input}`;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{props.label}</label>
        <input className={inputClasses} {...field} {...props}  id={props.name} placeholder={props?.placeholder}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: If I understood your description correctly, the first test has invalid data and the button should be disabled, right? If that is right why are you expecting it to be enabled?

Comment: Can you add the code of `MockedSignUpFormView` component?

Comment: Just as @DenisRoy says, remove the `not.`, or change the whole assertion to
`expect(signUpBtn).toBeDisabled()`, both ways should work

Comment: @DenisRoy no the test passes if i remove the .not() or add it. It just keeps passing even if it shouldn't

Comment: @Benji no the test passes if i remove the .not() or add it. It just keeps passing even if it shouldn't

Comment: Yes, tks. Just saw it and it wont help. What you need to add is the `form`code with the validation, in this case i believe its the `SignUpFormView`,

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto added SignUpFormView

Comment: The problem now its related to `Input` componnet - Its a custom component or you are using some 3rd library? Can you also show the code if its a custom component?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto added. sorry for the trouble

Comment: I've created an code sample and everything worked as expected (Throw an error on first test). Strange, maybe I'm missing something... Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-disabled-button-test-itev93?file=/src/SignUpFormView.spec.js) - it might help you.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto So there isn't any problem in the logic right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Right, no problem at all. Cheers!

Comment: @H.b did you find the problem? I also cannot make assertions around Formik to get working...

Comment: @Tomek I don't think I got this solved. Sorry